# How to open a JS file in Blazor?

Tags: javascript, blazor

In my _Host.cshtml file, I have a <script src="/_content/JS/Example.js>, linking to a simple JS file that has the line; console.log('test').

When I check the console of my browser, I receive the error; localhost:5000/_content/JS/Example.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found).
Blazor does not seem to be able to find my JS file.
For reference the file is located in the wwwroot folder of the BlazorApp, in a folder called JS.

Is there something wrong with my syntax? I would like to be able to access functions located within JSfiles in future,

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths, where the paths are relative to the `wwwroot`

```
<script src="~/JS/Example.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS file needs to be inside of the wwwroot folder. In your _Host.cshtml file, also make sure the path to include the file is relative. If the _content folder is an immediate child folder of wwwroot you would do something like this:

```
<script src="~/_content/JS/Example.js" />
```